# Ruby on Rails update multiple records in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, batch-insert

hi i have a rails app in which i want to create multiple records in the single query

this is my code

```
   inserts = []

    1000.times do
      inserts.push "user name"
    end

    inserts = inserts.map {|bar| "(#{bar.to_s})"}.join(",")

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "INSERT INTO `user_dat`.`user_inserts` (`name`) VALUES #{inserts}"
```

What error i am getting is the error in the mysql syntax

```
INSERT INTO `batch_insert`.`batch_inserts` (`name`) VALUES (user name),(user name),(user name),(user name),(user name),(user name),(user name).... upto 1000
```

i know i want it like ("user name"), ("user name") 
but i am not able to achieve it can someone please tell me how can i achieve this format of values

Comment: It seems that you forgot the quotes in your query: VALUES ('user name')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is only to put quotes around usernames, the answer is to replace string `inserts = inserts.map {|bar| "(#{bar.to_s})"}.join(",")`

with
`inserts = inserts.map {|bar| %Q[("#{bar.to_s}")]}.join(",")`

Comment: its giving the values like this "(user name)","(user name)","(user name)","(user name)"
but i want like ("user name ")

Comment: the inverted commas should be inside the bracket

Comment: @user4965201 Sure about first comment: I've edited my code. That's a typo :)
Don't understand aout inverted commas: can you please explain clearly?

Comment: i wanted ("user name") but i ws getting "(username)". though the edit is correct now .

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a model for that table? Then you could just use plain ActiveRecord:

```
data = 1.upto(10000).map { |i| { name: "User #{i}" } }
User.create data
```